# Combining several .txt files in matlab - program is too slow

Tags: performance, matlab

I wrote the following program to combine several .txt files to create one big file. The files are named chronologicaly and have the same number of columns.
The problem however is that it's very slow. Would you happen to have any ideas how to improve this?

```
Files=495; %number of files
NoFile=0; 

for x=272:(Files+272)
    cd 'xxx'
    name=sprintf('220%d.txt',x); 
    aktuellesFile = fopen(name);
    allText = textscan(currentFile,'%s','delimiter','\n');  
    numberOfLines = length(allText{1});
    fclose(aktuellesFile);
    T=readtable (name);

for j=1:225 %number of columns
    for i=1:numberOfLines
        K{i+NoFile,j}=T{i,j}; 
    end
end

    NoFile=i+NoFile;
end

cd 'xxx'
Neu=array2table(K);
ffile=sprintf('final%i.txt',x); 
writetable(Neu, 'output.txt');
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: use the profiler to see which lines are slow.  If your writing to a network location you *may* be quicker writing locally and then moving to the network

Comment: your file read is not efficient, your nested loop is not efficient, and quite honestly, if each of your file is large, Matlab might not even be able to handle it. Easiest way is to do this in bash or cmd using `cat` if you prefer to do it in matlab, you can remove the nested for loop.